# Meteor. Get full object using _id after a previous partial publish

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, meteor

I'm using meteor and meteor.angular.

I have a list of documents which are published by meteor with a restricted number of fields, since I don't need the full objects just for the list.

```
Meteor.publish("trackers", function () {
return Trackers.find({}, 
    {fields: 
        {
            'projectTracker.projectSPID':1,
            'projectTracker.projectName':1,
            'projectTracker.date':1
        }
    });
```

});

Then, clicking through on one of the list items, I use the object's _id to subscribe to a second Meteor.publish that I hoped would return the full object.

```
Meteor.publish("trackerBy_id", function (id) {
return Trackers.find({
    '_id': id
});
});
```

But, the _id is already with the client data, there is no update and I just get the limited object I was using for the original list rather than the single full object.

Using url params does cause the full object to be published.

```
Meteor.publish("trackerBy_params", function (SPID,date) {
return Trackers.find({
    'projectTracker.projectSPID': SPID, 
    'projectTracker.date': date
});
});
```

How can I use _id when a limited dataset already exists and trigger Meteor to publish the full object?

Comment: I guess you have to deal with it in your route settings: one route = one structure per collection. I am not sure of that, but your question match the behavior I observed once. Basically (assuming you don't want to change the parent page), what you need is to load a yield template with the details of your object, and attach your second subscription to it.

Comment: Your pattern *should* work, I use it myself. I suspect you are not waiting on the second subscription.